# State space representation using a given nilppotent matrix

Tags: control-systems, state-space

I want to build a question on state space using a given, nilpotent matrix, $A$.

$$q[n+1]=Aq[n]+Bx[n]$$
$$y[n]=Cq[n]+Dx[n]$$

Usually, I am using the canonical form so there is no problem extracting $A,B,C,D$ from the difference equation of the system. Given a nilpotent $A$, How do I choose reasonable $B,C,D$? can I simply go with the canonical form? Is there anything I should be aware of?

Comment: There's not enough detail here.  If A is nilpotent, then the system as a whole is deadbeat.  That's a pretty specific behavior.  So what's the specific system you're starting with?  Or otherwise what's the further context of the question at hand?

Comment: @TimWescott what do you mean by "deadbeat"? Do you mean that this is a redundant system? My goal is to give a HW question. This is not a system that is supposed to be functional in any way. I do am not starting with any system and I am not limited by the further context of the question.

Comment: A deadbeat system is one that has a response that settles out in finite time.

Comment: A nilpotent matrix can normally be reduced to a lower triangular matrix; which might speed up calcs and reduce the order to a usable one.  Tim is right, an explicit example would be usefull.